Excel index by category
I am trying to modify an existing formula to give more detail.
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(E2,A:A,0)+MATCH(1,FREQUENCY(1,N(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(E2,A:A,0)+1):A$15<>"")),0)-1)

Currently I have the forumla in H2:H5 to find the totals, i am now looking to see if this can be split into different categories e.g. in the example A in column F, B+C in column G.

Note:
Column A consists of merged cells with differing amounts of rows (minimum 2).
Any help on this would be much appreciated.
Tom

You could try using the following formula:


• Formula used in cell F2 , formula needs to fill down:
=LET(
     _Code, SCAN(,$A$2:$A$15,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x,y))),
     SUM((_Code=$E2)*($B$2:$B$15="A")*$C$2:$C$15))


• Formula used in cell G2 , formula needs to fill down:
=LET(
     _Code, SCAN(,$A$2:$A$15,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x,y))),
     SUM((_Code=$E2)*($B$2:$B$15<>"A")*($B$2:$B$15<>"")*$C$2:$C$15))


However, if applicable using PIVOTBY() one single formula for the whole summary:


=LET(
     _Code, SCAN(,A2:A15,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x,y))),
     _Cat, B2:B15,
     _Ncat, IFS(_Cat="","",_Cat<>"A","Other Qty",1,_Cat&" Qty"),
     PIVOTBY(_Code,_Ncat,C2:C15,SUM,,0,,1,,_Ncat<>""))


Also, for avoiding empty rows while taking entire ranges for calculations one can take advantage of using TRIMRANGE() features.
=LET(
     _Data, DROP($A.:.$C,1),
     _Code, SCAN(,TAKE(_Data,,1),LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x,y))),
     SUM((_Code=$E2)*(INDEX(_Data,,2)="A")*DROP(_Data,,2)))


And,
=LET(
     _Data, DROP($A.:.$C,1),
     _Code, SCAN(,TAKE(_Data,,1),LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x,y))),
     SUM((_Code=$E2)*(INDEX(_Data,,2)<>"A")*(INDEX(_Data,,2)<>"")*DROP(_Data,,2)))


However, personally I don't use and also its highly recommended to avoid using entire range instead using Structured References (aka Tables) is better because the formulas will auto adjust within the formulas as well, we are not considering the entire ranges.

The same modifications can be applied in the following as well:
=LET(
     _Data, DROP(A.:.C,1),
     _Code, SCAN(,TAKE(_Data,,1),LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x,y))),
     _Cat, INDEX(_Data,,2),
     _Ncat, IFS(_Cat="","",_Cat<>"A","Other Qty",1,_Cat&" Qty"),
     PIVOTBY(_Code,_Ncat,DROP(_Data,,2),SUM,,0,,1,,_Ncat<>""))


However, if you insist in considering the entire ranges, then can use the following as well, but note that it takes the Qty as a base for the last row, as the Code column can't be taken since those are merged (the following is for only E2:
=LET(
     _LastRow, MATCH(2,1/($C:$C<>"")),
     _Data, $A$2:INDEX($A:$C,_LastRow,),
     _Filter, FILTER(_Data,INDEX(_Data,,2)<>""),
     _FillD, SCAN(,TAKE(_Filter,,1),LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x,y))),
     SUM((_FillD=$E2)*(INDEX(_Filter,,2)="A")*DROP(_Filter,,2))) 


This one is for the entire A Qty, similarly one can do it for the other:


=LET(
     _LastRow, MATCH(2,1/($C:$C<>"")),
     _Data, $A$2:INDEX($A:$C,_LastRow,),
     _Filter, FILTER(_Data,INDEX(_Data,,2)<>""),
     _FillD, SCAN(,TAKE(_Filter,,1),LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x,y))),
     MAP(E2:E5, LAMBDA(z, SUM((_FillD=z)*(INDEX(_Filter,,2)="A")*DROP(_Filter,,2)))))



@TomRGarr best possible option is to convert your ranges into Structured References aka Tables using whole entire range is not recommended because it slows down the working functionality of excel as you will be iterating through all empty cells.

With REDUCE:
=LET(
    last_cell, XLOOKUP(TRUE, C:C <> "", C:C, , , -1),
    data_w_total, A2:last_cell,
    data, FILTER(data_w_total, INDEX(data_w_total, , 2) <> ""),
    code, SCAN(, INDEX(data, , 1), LAMBDA(last_nz, cur, IF(cur, cur, last_nz))),
    cat, INDEX(data, , 2),
    qty, INDEX(data, , 3),
    qty_for_code, LAMBDA(acc, c,
        LET(
            qty_a, SUM(FILTER(qty, (code = c) * (cat = "A"))),
            total, SUM(FILTER(qty, code = c)),
            VSTACK(acc, HSTACK(c, qty_a, total - qty_a, total))
        )
    ),
    REDUCE(TEXTSPLIT("Code,A Qty,Other Qty,Total", ","), UNIQUE(code), qty_for_code)
)

With PIVOTBY:
=LET(
    last_cell, XLOOKUP(TRUE, C:C <> "", C:C, , , -1),
    data_w_total, A2:last_cell,
    data, FILTER(data_w_total, INDEX(data_w_total, , 2) <> ""),
    code, SCAN(, INDEX(data, , 1), LAMBDA(last_nz, cur, IF(cur, cur, last_nz))),
    cat, IF(INDEX(data, , 2) = "A", "A Qty", "Other Qty"),
    qty, INDEX(data, , 3),
    PIVOTBY(code, cat, qty, SUM)
)




Formula in F2:
 =LET(f,INDEX,r,COUNTA(C:C),z,B2:f(B:B,r),PIVOTBY(SCAN(,A2:f(A:A,r),LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b="",a,b))),IF(z="A","A","Other")&" Qty",C2:f(C:C,r),SUM,,0,,1,,z<>""))

